# Heap Header and free() in C

Tags: c

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a resource that gave an in-depth explanation of the heap. I would like to know more about the headers utilized in practice and how the free() function actually "deallocates" memory by deleting the header information. Many resources just give the generic

```
    struct heapHeader
     {
       heapHeader* next;
       heapHeader* previous;
       unsigned int size;
     }
```

and then go on to say that this is never implemented in practice. So, to sum it up, I would like to know more about how heap headers are implemented in "practice" and how functions such as free() interact with said headers.

Comment: This will be implementation specific.  The C standard does not tell one exactly how to implement a heap, it simply states the semantics of a C program.  Any implementation which adheres to those semantics is valid.  I would suggest downloading an open source implementation of C (GNU C works.)

Comment: Find the [`dlmalloc`](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) (Doug Lea Malloc) code for one very serious, production quality implementation.  Look in K&R2 for another implementation.  Off-hand, I don't know whether GNU C Library uses `dlmalloc` or its own, but if it uses its own, look at that.  Perl includes its own `malloc`; you get to choose whether it uses it; that would be a fourth resource.

Comment: The malloc implementation in the GNU C Library is indeed based on Doug Lea's allocator. But of course it has grown its own hair, like threads going to separate arenas under contention and whatnot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C language standard does not define the specifics of a heap. It specifies malloc, calloc, realloc and free in terms of what task they perform, their parameters, and what the programmer can do with the result.

If you ask for implementations details, you are tempted to make assumptions that might bite you later. Unless you have very specific reasons to do so, you shouldn't need to investigate the inner workings. The way malloc and free work may change with the next OS revision, the next compiler version, or even the compile options used.

Answer (score 2):

Following is an interesting article: comprehensive, descriptive, about heap management.

[1]
http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/209-linux-memory-management

simple implementation example:

[2] http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node45.html

Hope that helps.